# What does this mean in the windows command line tool Cmder?

Tags: cmder

I use Cmder as my command line tool, recently I found this:

[image]

Why does it display *{git}* and *{lamb}*?
I installed git globally, and this Cmder include mysysgit.

Comment: Also, furthering what @Maximus said.  What you are seeing specifically, will happen if there is an error with `clink` and maybe also with your `git` installation or the font that you are using doesn't include the `λ` (lambda) character.

Answer (score 1):

cmder is just a repack of ConEmu, clink and msysgit. And what you see in curly brackets are clink's macros.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by updating `clink`:

1. Download portable Zip Clink from http://mridgers.github.io/clink/
2. Extract and replace files in your `cmder/vendor/clink` folder
3. Restart `Cmder`.